# To boil red bell pepper or to use a grounded one?

Tags: bell-peppers

I imagine you could add cuts of red bell pepper to a stew or you could dry it and ground it(I believe this would make it a mild paprika) and add it in that form.

What sort of flavour difference will the two different methods bring?

Comment: You seem to be asking the question: what's the difference between stewed red pepper and paprika.  Flavors are pretty hard to describe - especially the subtle differences in flavor between fresh and dried fruit - but you could do this experiment yourself pretty easily (assuming you have access to fresh peppers and to paprika).

Answer (score 2):

Paprika is, generally speaking, dried red bell pepper...though some varieties differ.  Remember, drying changes and concentrates flavor.  The flavor will be different.  Think of them as different ingredients.  Fresh and dried ingredients behave quite differently.  Think about the difference between fresh and dried herbs, for example.  Will it sweeten your stew?  It probably depends on the actual ingredients. Probably, but maybe in different ways.  Give it a shot, do a side-by-side comparison, and report your results here.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a dozen different types of paprika.  In the US, you'll generally see regular, 'sweet', 'hot', 'smoked', 'Hungarian', and 'Spanish', although there are multiple types of Spanish and Hungarian paprika.

The drying usually brings out a little bit of bitterness (and sometimes smokiness, depending on how it was dried), rather than just sweetness, so no, it won't give the same sweetness that you'd get from a fresh capsicum.

Drying also tends to lose some essential oils in most flavorings ... which is why dried and fresh herbs can be dramatically different in flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have said that the flavour of the pepper won't be the same. The effect on the flavour of the dish will be even more different, as the paprika flavour will be evenly distributed in the sauce while the pieces of pepper will retain much of their flavour.

Don't underestimate the effect on the final dish of *texture*. A stew without pieces of vegetables in is just meat cooked in gravy, not much of a stew at all.

In many dishes you'll use both. My chilli, for example, is heavy on the veg, and has chopped peppers in it. It also has paprika (two types) in addition to the other spices.